# Casting to `*mut` overrules the reference not being `mut`

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I was casting a field of a struct to a `*mut` pointer, so I declared that struct's reference as mutable. But then I started getting warnings that the `mut` modifier is not required. That seemed weird to me, I'm clearly mutating something, yet declaring it as `mut` is unnecessary? This leads me to this minimal example:

```rust
struct NonMut {
    bytes: [u8; 5]
}

impl NonMut {
    pub fn get_bytes(&self) -> &[u8] {
        &self.bytes
    }
}

fn potentially_mutate(ptr: *mut u8) {
    unsafe { *ptr = 0 }
}

fn why(x: &NonMut) {
    let ptr = x.get_bytes().as_ptr() as *mut u8;
    
    potentially_mutate(ptr);

}

fn main() {
    let x = NonMut { bytes: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] };
    println!("{}", x.get_bytes()[0]);

    why(&x);
    
    println!("{}", x.get_bytes()[0]);
}
```

```
1
0
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f8e318a32f4301476ca0183bcbeebfe4)

Obviously dereferencing the pointer requires unsafe code, but from the perspective of someone just writing their own app and deciding to call `why`, perhaps defined in an external crate, this behaviour seems completely unexpected. You pass a clearly nonmutable reference somewhere, the borrow checker marks your code as correct, but under the hood there is a mutable reference created for that struct. This could cause multiple living mutable references being created to `NonMut` without the user of `why` ever knowing about that.

Is this behaviour as expected? Shouldn't casting to `*mut` require the operand to be `mut` in the first place? Is there a compelling reason as to why it is not required?

Comment: I don't get any warning

Comment: @Stargateur The warning only comes out if you have a local mut variable of type `NonMut` and use it to get a mut* and mutate through that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem #1: `potentially_mutate` is incorrectly marked as a safe function while it can cause undefined behavior (e.g. what if I pass in an invalid pointer?). So we need to mark it `unsafe` and document our assumptions for safe usage:

```rust
/// Safety: must pass a valid mutable pointer.
unsafe fn potentially_mutate(ptr: *mut u8) {
    unsafe { *ptr = 0 }
}
```

So now we need to rewrite `why`:

```rust
fn why(x: &NonMut) {
    let ptr = x.get_bytes().as_ptr() as *mut u8;
    
    unsafe {
        potentially_mutate(ptr);
    }
}
```

And now we've exposed our problem #2: we violate the assumptions `potentially_mutate` makes. We are passing it in a pointer that points to immutable data, claiming it is mutable. This is undefined behavior! It wouldn't make any difference if we had `x: &mut NonMut` either, which is why you'd get a warning if you tried that. What matters is this:

```
pub fn get_bytes(&self) -> &[u8] {
    &self.bytes
}
```

Here we construct an immutable reference to a slice of bytes when you call the method, regardless of whether your `x: &NonMut` is mutable or not. If we wanted to mutate the bytes we would need to also make:

```
pub fn get_bytes_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [u8] {
    &mut self.bytes
}
```

You would still not be done however, as `as_ptr` states:

> The caller must also ensure that the memory the pointer (non-transitively) points to is never written to (except inside an UnsafeCell) using this pointer or any pointer derived from it. If you need to mutate the contents of the slice, use as_mut_ptr.

And `as_mut_ptr` states:

> The caller must ensure that the slice outlives the pointer this function returns, or else it will end up pointing to garbage.

So to get your example correct and safe:

```rust
struct Mut {
    bytes: [u8; 5]
}

impl Mut {
    pub fn get_bytes(&self) -> &[u8] {
        &self.bytes
    }
    
    pub fn get_bytes_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [u8] {
        &mut self.bytes
    }
}

unsafe fn potentially_mutate(ptr: *mut u8) {
    *ptr = 0
}

fn whynot(x: &mut Mut) {
    unsafe {
        let slice = x.get_bytes_mut(); // Keep slice alive.
        let ptr = slice.as_mut_ptr();
        potentially_mutate(ptr);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = Mut { bytes: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] };
    println!("{}", x.get_bytes()[0]);
    whynot(&mut x);
    println!("{}", x.get_bytes()[0]);
}
```

Comment: I agree with the comments on how to make this better, but my original question stands -- why can I make a `*mut u8` from a nonmutable reference `&[u8]` acquired from a nonmutable reference `&NonMut`? It seems to me that the borrow checker should not allow that cast.

Comment: @V0ldek Because it is not undefined behavior to construct such pointers, only to *use* them incorrectly. This contrasts with references, where it is undefined behavior to even construct them.

Comment: Why is it undefined behavior for references and for pointers it is not?

Comment: @V0ldek Because the Rust compiler is allowed to, and does make assumptions about mutable references, such as non-aliasing and exclusive access.

Comment: But why not about pointers, then?

Comment: @V0ldek The whole point of pointers is that they can express things that you can't do with ordinary references due to their stricter requirements, e.g. C FFI or the runtime mutability check that Skgland's answer suggests. If pointers and references were *exactly* the same, there would not be any point in having both in the same language.

Comment: @V0ldek Because you can, fo example, do `&mut v as *mut T as *const T as *mut T` (the first `as *mut T` should not be required but currently is required because of a bug in the compiler IIRC). Or you can do that in multiple statements, and _it is valid to dereference that pointer_. There are some use cases for that (for example, `std::ptr::NonNull` contains a `*const T` but let you get a `*mut T`. The only time this is disallowed is when you derive the pointer from a shared _reference_.

Comment: @orlp The point about making `potentially_mutate()` `unsafe` can be argued. This function is private, so as long as no unsound code is exposed, this can be fine to leave it safe to reduce the noise. It depends entirely on the programmer's opinion (it is correct that we strive for the smallest safe encapsulation, and function is a grate candidate, but sometimes you can only make the whole module sound or even the whole crate).

Comment: @orlp It is interesting that `as_mut_ptr()` requires the **slice** to be alive. I'll argue that the meaning is for the **underlying storage** (the array in this case), since there's no reason to require the slice to be alive more than requiring that for any reference (i.e. require that `&mut v` will stay alive in `*(&mut v as *mut T)`

Comment: @orlp Got it: it needs the **slice** (`[T]`, unsized) to be alive, not **the reference to it** (`&{mut }[T]`). It can't require the underlying storage to be alive - because, for example, resizing a `Vec` doesn't kill it but yet invalidates any reference to the slice it used to contain. So, no, you don't need to keep the variable `slice` alive.

Comment: @orlp In short: `unsafe { potentially_mutate(x.get_bytes_mut().as_mut_ptr()); }` is concise and valid.

Answer (score 0):

You are not casting from `&u8` to `*mut u8` directly.

```rust
fn allowed(x: &[u8]) {
    let x_ptr   = x.as_ptr();    // &[u8]     -> *const u8
    let _ptr = x_ptr as *mut u8; // *const u8 -> *mut u8 
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0d26e0868c0995a1a10b03864e539299)

Casting from `*const T` to `*mut T` is allowed.

This might be useful if you want to abstract over the mutability and have some runtime check that tells you whether your pointer came from a mutable or immutable source.

Directly casting an immutable reference to a mutable pointer is not allowed, though, and as such the following example fails to compile as expected:

```rust
fn not_allowed(x: &[u8]) {
    let x_ref  = &x[0];          // &[u8] -> &u8
    let _ptr = x_ref as *mut u8; // &u8   -> *mut u8
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f64237c88d27a47f08febe0163014f81)

Note that while the first example is allowed and as we aren't using the mutable raw pointer there shouln't even be undefined behaviour.
Dereferencing or turning the mutable raw pointer into a mutable reference, would result in undefined behaviour. Because the raw pointer is derived from a shared reference and there being no UnsafeCell involved, as others have pointet out.

Comment: This is just wrong. Creating a mutable reference from a shared reference is UB, PERIOD. No matter what is in the middle. @orlp has answered correctly.

Comment: I did not intend to say that it was not UB. The first snippet just tries to explain in smaller steps what exactly is happening in the question and the second does not even compile.